# Using Syntax Parameters in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

I'm trying to define a macro that generates an anonymous function taking one argument named it, for succinctness, so that instead of

`(λ (it) body)`
I can write
`(λλ body)`

(In other words, `(λλ body)` transforms to `(λ (it) body)`)

```
(define-syntax-parameter it #f)
(define-syntax λλ
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ body)
     (λ (x) (syntax-parameterize ((it x)) body)))))
(λλ (< it 0)) ; For testing
```

I get `operators.rkt:13:28: ?: literal data is not allowed; no #%datum syntax transformer is bound in the transformer environment in: #f` at `(define-syntax-parameter if #f)`, but as far as I can tell, this is exactly like the example given in racket's doc for how to use `define-syntax-parameter`. I can suppress the error by replacing `#f` with a function (I used `member`, but not for any real reason), but after doing that, I get `operators.rkt:17:38: x: identifier used out of context in: x`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You left out the `syntax-id-rules` part in the [example](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html?q=syntax-parameterize&q=syntax-parameterize#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/stxparam..rkt%29._syntax-parameterize%29%29). It's the part that specifies that `it` should expand to `x`. Alternatively, you can use [`make-rename-transformer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=make-rename-transformer#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-rename-transformer%29%29):

```
#lang racket
(require racket/stxparam)

(define-syntax-parameter it #f)
(define-syntax λλ
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ body)
     (λ (x) (syntax-parameterize ([it (make-rename-transformer #'x)]) body)))))
((λλ (< it 0)) 5)
((λλ (< it 0)) -5)
```

=>

```
#f
#t
```

Comment: To clarify this further, the thing that the syntax parameter is "bound to" lives at the syntax world -- so you don't want to use `x` since that's a runtime thing, instead you want to use `#'x`.  But you really want to create a kind of a macro that *expands* to `#'x`, and therefore the `syntax-id-rules` or the more convenient `make-rename-transformer` shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax parameters are not the only way to implement the macro you have in mind. A simpler (IMO) way is to just use `datum->syntax` to inject the identifier `it`:

```
(define-syntax (λλ stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_ body ...)
     (with-syntax ((it (datum->syntax stx 'it)))
       #'(λ (it) body ...)))))
```

To use your example:

```
(define my-negative? (λλ (< it 0)))
(my-negative? -1)   ;; => #t
```

Comment: Actually, I believe this is a fine use of `syntax-parameterize`. See Barzilay et al.'s "Keeping it Clean" paper.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll soften my wording a bit. I still think it's overkill when `datum->syntax` will do, but your answer is good (+1).

Comment: I think the key is that you can get non-hygiene in `syntax-rules` and not have to switch to the heavier `syntax-case`.

Comment: @stchang That is actually a very good point, and I'll remember that next time before I start telling people "no, you can't break hygiene in `syntax-rules`". :-P

Comment: *argh*.  ...sorry, but as someone who invested so much effort on explaining why it's a bad idea, it looks like I'm morally obliged to downvote you on this one (for the first time...).  The main real (and highlevel) problem with `datum->syntax` is that it looks like it works, only it can bite you later horribly.  It's especially effective at getting bugs that are bad enough to make people go back to the "simple world of `defmacro`".

Comment: @EliBarzilay I'm in the process of reading [Keeping it Clean with Syntax Parameters](http://www.barzilay.org/misc/stxparam.pdf), and reading through that, I can see how the non-parameterised approach can lead you down a giant rabbit hole. Thanks for the pointer! +1